# Error message: Maximum Recursion exhausted even with OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a function that will have as input a start date and a number of minutes. The function will add the number of minutes to the start date and it will output an end date, but only considering work hours and excluding weekends and holidays.

You can see part of the function below.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DataFimPrevisto] (@tempoPrevisto real, @DataIni datetime)
RETURNS datetime
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DataFim datetime;
    DECLARE @calculo TABLE( xend datetime, [minutes] int);
    WITH 
    drange (date_start, date_end) AS 
    (      
        SELECT 
        CAST(@DataIni AS DATE) AS date_start, 
        CAST(DATEADD( YEAR, 1, @DataIni) AS DATE) AS date_end
    ), 
    dates0 (adate, date_end) AS 
    (                     
        SELECT date_start, date_end FROM drange 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(day,  1, adate), date_end FROM dates0 WHERE adate < date_end
    ), 
    dates (adate) AS 
    (                                
        SELECT adate FROM dates0 
        WHERE DATEPART(dw , adate) NOT IN ('1', '7') AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM BAS_PeriodosExcecoes B WHERE B.Trabalhavel = 0 AND B.DataInicio = adate)
    ), 
    hours (hour_start, hour_end) AS 
    (                 
        SELECT  8.5*60, 12.5*60 
        UNION
        SELECT 13.5*60, 18*60
    ), 
    hours_friday (hour_start, hour_end) AS 
    (                 
        SELECT  8*60, 14*60
    ), 
    datehours (xstart, xend) AS 
    (   
        SELECT * 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
            DATEADD(minute, hour_start, CAST(adate AS datetime)) xstart, 
            DATEADD(minute, hour_end  , CAST(adate AS datetime)) xend
            FROM dates AS d, hours AS h
            WHERE DATEPART(dw , adate) <> '6'

            UNION

            SELECT T2.xstart, T2.xend
            FROM
            (
                SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.xstart ORDER BY T.xend ASC) AS rank 
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                    @DataIni xstart, 
                    DATEADD(minute, hour_end, CAST(adate AS datetime)) xend
                    FROM dates AS d, hours AS h
                    WHERE adate = CAST( @DataIni AS DATE) AND DATEADD(minute, hour_end, CAST(adate AS datetime)) > @DataIni AND DATEPART(dw , adate) <> '6'
                ) T 
            ) T2 
            WHERE T2.rank = 1

            UNION

            SELECT 
            DATEADD(minute, hour_start, CAST(adate AS datetime)) xstart, 
            DATEADD(minute, hour_end  , CAST(adate AS datetime)) xend
            FROM dates AS d, hours_friday AS h
            WHERE DATEPART(dw , adate) = '6'

            UNION

            SELECT T2.xstart, T2.xend
            FROM
            (
                SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.xstart ORDER BY T.xend ASC) AS rank 
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                    @DataIni xstart, 
                    DATEADD(minute, hour_end, CAST(adate AS datetime)) xend
                    FROM dates AS d, hours_friday AS h
                    WHERE adate = CAST( @DataIni AS DATE) AND DATEADD(minute, hour_end, CAST(adate AS datetime)) > @DataIni AND DATEPART(dw , adate) = '6'
                ) T 
            ) T2 
            WHERE T2.rank = 1
        ) T3 WHERE T3.xstart >= @DataIni
    ),
    cumulative (xend, [minutes]) AS
    (
        SELECT t.xend, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, xstart, xend)) OVER (ORDER BY xstart) AS [minutes]
        FROM datehours AS t
    )
    INSERT INTO @calculo
    SELECT TOP 1 xend, [minutes]
    FROM cumulative
    WHERE [minutes] >= @tempoPrevisto
    ORDER BY cumulative.xend ASC;

    SET @DataFim = (SELECT DATEADD( MINUTE, @tempoPrevisto - MAX([minutes]), MAX( [xend])) FROM @calculo);
    RETURN(@DataFim);
END;
```

When I execute this function with

```
SELECT dbo.DataFimPrevisto( 21240, DATETIMEFROMPARTS( 2023, 1, 25, 6, 0, 0, 0)) OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

SSMS returns the error message

> The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Even tho I'm using OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0).

Comment: Switch to a tally, then you can't get this problem. As an added benefit, they are far more performant too.

Comment: The definition of your function isn't complete either.

Comment: @Larnu I've updated the post with the full function. How would I go about creating a tally table here?

Comment: As you have a multi-line scalar function, the `MAXRECURSION` setting needs to be on your recursive CTE in the statement, not outside it. But, again, I'd suggest switching to a Tally, and (also) an inline table value function.